# How to write JavaPairDStream to Redis?

Tags: java, apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming

I am using spark 1.5.0 and java 7.

Input is from kafka in form of different json objects with a `type` field. Eg:

```
{'type': 'alpha', ...}
{'type': 'beta', ...}
...
```

I am creating a `JavaPairDStream<String, Integer>` from this input data corresponding to counts of each event type.

I want to store this data to redis. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the `foreachRDD` and `forEach` functions to achieve this as follows:

```
wordCounts.foreachRDD(
    new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>, Void>() {
        public Void call(JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> rdd) {
            rdd.foreach(
                new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String,Integer>>() {
                    public void call(Tuple2<String,Integer> wordCount) {
                        System.out.println(wordCount._1() + ":" + wordCount._2());
                        JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost");
                        Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
                        jedis.select(0);
                        jedis.set(wordCount._1(), wordCount._2().toString());
                    }
                }
            );
            return null;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I hoped that someone would point you to this before, but I think sorted sets are more beneficial to your case than simple keys (which you are using by using `SET`).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new connection pool for every single RDD is very inefficient. I suggest creating one connection for each partition:

```
wordCount.mapPartitions(p->{
 Jedis jd = new Jedis(getJedisConfig());
 while (p->hasNext()) {
   Tuple2<String,Integer> data = p.next();
   String word = data._1();
   Integer cnt = data._2();
   jd.set(word,count); // or any other format of save to Redis
 }
}
)
```